# «Смотри как красиво!» — запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика, сложное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая в подобных предложениях?

> Смотри(,) как красиво!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом сложном предложении запятая нужна, так как имеются две основы: [ты] *смотри* (сказуемое — глагол в повелительном наклонении, подлежащее отсутствует, но подразумевается) и *красиво* — слово категории состояния (в школьной грамматике рассматривается как вид наречия; описывает состояние природы, окружающей среды и обстановки).
***Смотри, как красиво!***

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
***― Смотри, как красиво!** ― не удержался Вайс* (Вадим Кожевников. Щит и меч. Книга вторая);
*― Погоди, ― произносит он одними губами, ― **смотри, как красиво!*** (Петр Алешковский. Седьмой чемоданчик);
***— Смотри, как здорово!** — крикнул Дауге* (Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Путь на Амальтею).

[Е. Карпова. Вопрос о статусе слов категории состояния](https://books.google.ee/books?id=0f4jEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=ySs4gRWWiD&sig=ACfU3U2zXPKcZeScKL7JpKoEgCCmbo8zYw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEl7Xa-5D-AhWQ6CoKHZPgDPkQ6AF6BAhNEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&f=false)